# Excel 2013 VBScript Range().Value doesn't update

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to achieve is to have some cells update when another cell is changed.

I want this to be able to see when a cell was first changed so I can check that a daily routine was actually punched into the log sheet on the correct day.

```
Public Function UDF_Signature(ByVal data, ByVal first, ByVal updated, ByVal update_times) As Date
If Range(update_times).Value = 0 Then
    Range(update_times).Value = "1"
    Range(first).Value = Now()
    Range(updated).Value = Now()
Else
    Range(update_times).Value = Range(update_times).Value + 1
    Range(updated).Value = Now()
End If

UDF_Signature = Now()
End Function
```

I've tried to debug it, when i hover over the different code lines i see the correct information, but when it comes to the first line after Then or Else it stops, no error, just stops. (Or my breakpoints after this line doesn't work...)

I've also tried to add Worksheets("Daily"). in front of Range to see if that helped since i have to Worksheets in this document.

The different cells in the sheet:

- Cell B177; is the signature field for the person that did the routine
  walk around.
- Cell B178; =UDF_Signature(B177;"B179";"B180";"B181")
- Cell B179; Should be updated with the date of the first change on signature cell
- Cell B180; Should be updated with the date of when the last update of the signature cell was made.
- Cell B181; Numbers of changes to the signature field. (And also to check if the first changed cell needs to be updated)

Comment: A UDF called from a worksheet formula cannot update the workbook - that's a restriction imposed on UDF's in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the method you're using, try the following.

1) In a standard code module, declare a boolean public variable and an Integer public variable, i.e.

```
Public cellUsed As Boolean
Public changeCount As Integer
```

2) Use the workbook open event to force the variables default values

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
cellUsed = False
changeCount = 0
End Sub
```

3) Use the worksheet change event to capture the input and change cells as required. e.g.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$177" Then 'The cell we are evaluating

Application.EnableEvents = False 'Prevent possibility of infinite loop
On Error GoTo Just_Incase: 'Make sure events are re-enabled in the case of an error
  If Not cellUsed Then ' Signature hasn't been updated since the workbook opened
     Range("B179").Value = Now ' Timestamp in B179
     cellUsed = True ' Update public variable, cell has now changed.
  End If

Range("B180").Value = Now ' Timestamp in B180
Range("B181").Value = changeCount
changeCount = changeCount + 1

Application.EnableEvents = True ' Re-enable events

On Error GoTo 0 'Reset error handling to default

End If

Exit Sub

Just_Incase:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for point in the correct direction @s-o ! It works just like I want it to work now :)

Answer (score 0):

A UDF called from a worksheet formula cannot update the workbook - that's a restriction imposed on UDF's in Excel.

https://support.microsoft.com/KB/170787?wa=wsignin1.0

> A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot
>   change the environment of Microsoft Excel. This means that such a
>   function cannot do any of the following:
>
> ```
> - Insert, delete, or format cells on the spreadsheet.  
> - Change another cell's value.  
> - Move, rename, delete, or add sheets to a workbook. 
> - Change any of the environment options, such as calculation mode or
>    screen views.  
> - Add names to a workbook.  
> - Set properties or execute most methods.
> ```
>
> The purpose of
>   user-defined functions is to allow the user to create a custom
>   function that is not included in the functions that ship with
>   Microsoft Excel. The functions included in Microsoft Excel also cannot
>   change the environment. Functions can perform a calculation that
>   returns either a value or text to the cell that they are entered in.
>   Any environmental changes should be made through the use of a Visual
>   Basic subroutine.
>
> During calculation, Excel examines the precedents of the cell that
>   contains a user-defined function. If not all precedents have been
>   calculated so far during the calculation process, Excel eventually
>   calls the user-defined function and passes a Null or Empty cell to the
>   function. Excel then makes sure that enough calculation passes occur
>   for all precedents to be calculated. During the final calculation
>   pass, the user-defined function is passed the current values of the
>   cells. This can cause the user-defined function to be called more
>   frequently than expected, and with unexpected arguments. Therefore,
>   the user-defined function may return unexpected values.

Your best bet may be to use either the `WorkSheet_Change` or the `Worksheet_Calculate` event